# How to recover a Ubuntu 20.04 live usb that crashed after uninstalling python?

Tags: 20.04, live-usb, data-recovery

I have foolishly uninstalled python from my Ubuntu 20.04  live usb... Now it won't boot past a black screen offering to enter ubuntu credetials. It accepts su as user and the pre-set password.

How do I recover my files? (I don't see them when mounting on Windows for example.)

I know as little, as this situation suggests. Please help.

Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.6 Focal Fossa live usb (amd64) with 9 Gb persistent partition.
Created using Rufus on Windows 10.

Comment: If your live USB is a live-only (and not persistent live) usb, reboot should reset it to the original (and working) operating system. Please explain/describe what system you have and how you created it; Version and flavour of Ubuntu (for example Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS or Lubuntu 23.10) and method + tool to put it onto the USB drive.

Comment: @sudodus I updated the question

Comment: A persistent live drive made with Rufus can be booted live-only: When at the grub menu, press 'e' and edit the line starting with 'linux': modify the word `persistent` to `nopersistent` (add the two letters 'no') and then continue booting by F10 or {ctrl + x}. You may try to repair the file system in the partition labeled `writable`, and then try to mount it and identlfy the files you want.

Comment: If you think that is too complicated, please boot from another USB drive according to answer by  user535733.

Answer (score 1):

A LiveUSB is not designed to be repaired. It's not really designed for regular use. It's intended for hardware testing and desktop environment preview.

- It's a real credit to Ubuntu that the testing/preview environment is good enough and robust enough to be misused as a persistent portable fully-featured system.

Make *another* LiveUSB-with-persistence using a working system. Boot it. Enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Use that environment to recover your files from the broken USB.

Comment: I'd disagree that a live USB (or any live ISO booted from anything) is not designed for regular use. It basically runs a regular system, just with a read-only filesystem base with new writes saved in ram/the persistent file. The fact that persistent USB's even exist is evidence that they're meant to be used over a longer term. Is there a Ubuntu source that says persistent live USB's are being misused by... using them?